# Создание пользователя и настройка пользоватей в MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Нужно удаленно создать логин/пароль для другого пользователя и дать доступ к базе.
В итоге получил нечто такое:

```
CREATE LOGIN somelogin WITH PASSWORD = 'passssssss';
USE SOMEDB;
CREATE USER someuser FOR LOGIN somelogin WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
GRANT CONTROL TO someuser;
```

Но некоторым из них надо дать доступ на создание других пользователей.

Как таким пользователям давать такой доступ?

Или, может быть, возможно создать двух пользователей с нужными настройками, и привязать к ним несколько логинов?

Comment: создайте роль, назначьте ей права, добавьте пользователей в эту ролью. вот тут посмотрите (подробно расписано с картинками интерфейса) http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/Create-a-user-defined-server-role-in-SQL-Server-2012-with-T-SQL-SSMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы создавать логины, нужно быть членом специальной роли `securityadmin` сервера:

```
EXEC [master]..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'LoginName', @rolename = N'securityadmin'
GO
```

В SqlServer 2012 и далее можно также:

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE [securityadmin] ADD MEMBER [LoginName]
GO
```

Чтобы создавать пользователей базы, нужно быть членом специальной роли `db_securityadmin` базы:

```
USE [Database]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_securityadmin', @membername = N'MemberName'
GO
```

В SqlServer 2012 и далее можно:

```
USE [Database]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_securityadmin] ADD MEMBER [MemberName]
GO
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А вот какие полномочия нужны, чтобы давать такие полномочия? =В

Comment: @RihardBrugekhaim, в базе нужно иметь роль `db_owner`, а на сервере - `sysadmin`.